# How to copy a directory using Copy task in gradle

Tags: gradle, directory, copy

I want to copy a range of files and whole directories to another directory in a single Copy task. I can copy individual files, and the *contents* of directories, but how do I copy the directory itself?

This is my task:

```
task myTask(type: Copy) {
    from 'path/to/file'
    from 'path/to/dir'
    into 'path/to/target'
}
```

which copies the file OK, but only the files in the dir. I want to end up with the contents of the dir in `path/to/target/dir` (not in `path/to/target`).

I found a work around by using:

```
task myTask(type: Copy) {
    from 'path/to/file'
    from 'path/to'
    into 'path/to/target'
    include 'dir'
}
```

But that is prone to name collisions. I actually have many files and dirs to copy, and I want to make it one task.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a book that is available for download on the Gradle website [here](http://www2.gradle.com/l/68052/2015-01-26/23s5)  or click "Get Free Ebook" [here](https://gradle.org/getting-started-gradle-java/): **"Gradle Beyond the Basics"** which provides a direct answer to your question on page 3 (*Transforming Directory Structure*).

Applied to your example the solution would be as follows:

```
    task myTask(type: Copy) {
        from 'path/to/file'
        from 'path/to/dir' {
            into 'dir'
        }
        into 'path/to/target'
    }
```

The limitation is that it will not dynamically determine the name of the second level target directory (*dir*) from the source but it is a clean approach.

Comment: @adam well it is a better solution than yours, because this is more "OO" - the customisation of behaviour is contained in the command, whereas yours is more like a callback or another into command

Comment: @Bohemian i see the same 4 lines in a different order :)

Answer (score 11):

The only solution I know for your problem:

```
task myTask(type: Copy) {
    into 'path/to/target'
    from 'path/to/file'

    into ('dir') {
       from 'path/to/dir'        
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that `into: ('dir')` construction works relatively to `path/to/target/` location

Comment: That is an improvement, but I can't believe there isn't a way to do this properly/simply

Comment: Upvote this people... this was the first correct answer.